# cannot interact with viewcontroller after segue

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

I have a rather bizarre problem. I have a game made in sprite kit with 2 view controllers, one for the game, one for the menu. when the game ends, the view controller segues back to the menu and closes the game window, this works fine the first time, but if you then go to play another game, lose and come back, for some reason you cannot interact with the menu view controller in any way. Here is my code, running from the SKScene:

```
        [self.view.window.contentViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"endGame" sender:self];
        [self.view.window performClose:nil]; //close the window
```

As I said before, it works the first time, but not the second, it displays the menu but you cant interact with it.

Comment: Use the notification to talk to your game view controller.

Comment: can you explain that a bit better please?

Comment: `SKScene` is a sub class of `UIView`.  So its view controller's job to transition to a different view controller.  Add an observer to your game view controller so that you can talk to it from the game scene when necessary.

Comment: I did that first, using an extra thread to monitor it, it came to the same result. There's no difference between trying it from the viewcontroller or the SKScene

Comment: Also, if it were the case as you said earlier, it wouldn't work the first time, I can get it to segue twice, its what comes next that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I worked out what the issue is. When you create a new view controller in the storyboard, it also creates a new window controller. I was using 2 window controllers in my app, by removing 1 of these and linking the menu window to the window controller for the game scene it fixed the problem.